# Database Seeder cannot find class with Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

When running `php artisan migrate --seed`, this error appears:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
Class 'CreateCharactersTable' not found.
```

Here is that that class:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CharacterSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('characters')->delete();

        DB::table('characters')->insert([
            'user_id'   => 999,
            'name'      => 'Susan Strong',
            'race'      => 'orc',
            'class'     => 'assassin',
            'image_location'    => null,
            'combat_level'      => '0',
            'base_str'  => 6,
            'base_int'  => 4,
            'base_apt'  => 5,
            'mod_str'   => 9,
            'mod_int'   => 5,
            'mod_apt'   => 7,
            'xp_str'    => 1,
            'xp_int'    => 2,
            'xp_apt'    => 1,
            'is_bot'    => 1,
            'created_at'=> '2017-04-02 17:53:02',
            'updated_at'=> '2017-04-02 17:53:02'
        ]);



        DB::table('characters')->insert([
            'user_id'   => 4,
            'name'      => 'Chale',
            'race'      => 'elf',
            'class'     => 'scholar',
            'image_location'    => null,
            'combat_level'      => '0',
            'base_str'  => 3,
            'base_int'  => 7,
            'base_apt'  => 5,
            'mod_str'   => 6,
            'mod_int'   => 10,
            'mod_apt'   => 6,
            'xp_str'    => 1,
            'xp_int'    => 2,
            'xp_apt'    => 1,
            'is_bot'    => 1,
            'created_at'=> '2017-04-02 17:53:02',
            'updated_at'=> '2017-04-02 17:53:
    }
}

?>
```

and the seeder:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Database\Seeds\CharacterSeeder;
use Database\Seeds\ClassesTableSeeder;
use Database\Seeds\RacesTableSeeder;
use Database\Seeds\UserTableSeeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(UserTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(CharacterSeeder::class);
        $this->call(RacesTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(ClassesTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

Running `composer dumpautoload` passes but does not remove the error. When it was only two seeders, User and Character, it ran well. Despite looking over the new seeders again and again, I cannot determine the error involved.

Any suggestions to get the seeder to run?

Thank you.

Comment: do composer dump-autoload and try to run seed again

Comment: @sumit as described in the question, this has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've imported all your seeders from a namespace, but they aren't in a namespace.

```
use Database\Seeds\CharacterSeeder;
use Database\Seeds\ClassesTableSeeder;
use Database\Seeds\RacesTableSeeder;
use Database\Seeds\UserTableSeeder;
```

Just remove those lines and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 15):

If you manually added the seeder files you should first run `composer dump-autoload`. This will regenerate the autoload_classmap.php file for you, see [Composer Dump-Autoload](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Class `'CreateCharactersTable'` should is Migration. You need check this migration file or class exists.

if you only use seeder . you can exec 

`php artisan db:seed`